# How to change datetime.Now without special characters?

Tags: c#, date

I am exporting a data from SQL Query into CSV and then renaming the csv file into a name-with-date however i have a problem with renaming the csv file to not have any special characters.

I have tried replacing the "." or "/" with an empty space but that does not bear fruitful for me. My code as per below :

```
string filepath1 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs\\import-contacts-" +
                   DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd").Replace('/', ' ') + ".csv";
```

My output should be import-contacts-20190606.csv

However i am getting import-contacts-2019.06.06.csv at the moment.

How can i fix my output?

Comment: No repro. `DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")` produces `2019.06.21`. It doesn't emit any slashes. `DateTime.Now.Date` is identical to `DateTime.Today`

Comment: Have you tried: `DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")` ?

Comment: Simply `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`

Comment: If you don't want a dot in the formatted string, *don't* include it in the format string. Use the format you actually want. Eg, `"yyyy-MM-dd"` or `"yyyyMMdd"` or anything else you want

Comment: If you're not specifying a culture you're using your local culture, and that uses slashes. Use a specific culture if you want a specific format.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I replaced to yyyyMMdd and that works perfect for me. I did not try that at first because i was assuming that the dot(.) is a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `.` from `ToString()`  method. Try like:

```
string  = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\Logs\import-contacts-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd").Replace('/', ' ') + ".csv";
```

**EDIT (per new req):**

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Date` [is identical to](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,1262) `DateTime.Today`

Comment: You are right, haven't seen Date at first look, edited

Comment: Lol this one works for me. I am so sorry guys i should've tried removing the dots myself first. but i thought the dots is a requirement. i removed the dots on my side and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: i do forgot one thing. i have to make the date 1 day before.. meaning -1.

can guide me on this?

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin  Added Edit, check it

Comment: Ah! So i can actually add AddDays and continue with ToString. That makes sense. Thanks @apomene !

Answer (score 3):

You can use string interpolation for this, to make it much clearer to read.  Also, just don't put anything in the string you don't want...

```
var filePath =  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +
    $"\\Logs\\import-contacts-{DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1):yyyyMMdd}.csv";
```

or (if you prefer a 1-liner)...

```
var filePath = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\\Logs\\import-contacts-{DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1):yyyyMMdd}.csv";
```

Here's a working example...

https://dotnetfiddle.net/aYAgVr

**Note** `DateTime.Now` would work exactly the same, since you're formatting the output to only show the date parts.  I'm just pedantic about not using a DateTime for a date!

Comment: why not put `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` into the string interpolation?

Comment: @MaximilianAst Purely because I split the code over 2 lines.  It irked me to have `$"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}" +` since it's already a string

Comment: @MaximilianAst I've added an example like that anyway.  Options are always a good thing :)

Comment: Since im on C# , isnt var on VB? or var represent the variable var on C#?
However based on the answers here , i have my problem on the date format solved.

i do forgot one thing. i have to make the date 1 day before.. meaning -1.

can guide me on this?

Comment: `var` is C# (and others), but VB is `Dim`.  I'll modify my answer to give you yesterday's date.  Check the example link to see it working.

Comment: @Archer - Hi Archer. by modifying your code , i got one that works with my string line. string attachFileLoc = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs\\import-contacts-"+ DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv"; ...... Thank you Archer!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're relying on the *current culture* to provide the right format, but *current* means different things to different users, and apparently does not produce the format you want.

The solution is simple, use a specific culture to get a specific format:

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

should always use dots as separators.

Answer (score 0):

It will work for you.

```
string path = string.Format(@"{0}Logs\import-contacts-{1}.csv", new object[] { AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") });
```